# How get already loaded module without callback?

Tags: requirejs

How get already loaded module without callback?

```
module_name = 'expected_module';
if(require.specified(module_name)) {
  module = require.get('module_name'); //I want to have here get function, but this function is absent in requirejs
  module.destructor();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a module is actually **loaded** you need to use `require.defined` not `require.specified`. `require.specified` only checks whether the module has been requested at some point. It may not be loaded *yet*.

Once you've checked with `require.defined` that the module *is* loaded, it is safe to just perform a `require` call with the module name as the first argument. The return value of the call will be the module. For instance:

```
if (require.defined("foo")) {
    var foo = require("foo");
    // Do stuff with foo...
}
```

Whereas generally you do need to pass an array of dependencies and a callback to `require` calls, RequireJS does support calling `require` like above. However, it will be successful *only* if the module is already loaded, but we check for that with `require.define`.

So your code should be modified to:

```
module_name = 'expected_module';
if(require.defined(module_name)) {
  module = require('module_name');
  module.destructor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
require(['expected_module'], function(module){

    module.destructor();   //call methods in your module

});
```

The `callback` is necessary since `require` loads all modules and their dependencies `async`. The code written inside callback executes only when all dependencies are loaded.